# Maybe Monad usage

Tags: haskell

Is it good practice to use the Maybe monad only when a function can result in an error in order to preserve type safety ?

In my current project I am doing operations on lists, for my get/set functions I have used the Maybe monad in order to prevent out of bound errors :

```
getCell :: [String] -> Int -> Int -> Maybe [String]
setCell :: [String] -> Int -> Int -> Maybe [String]
```

This to me, feels like the correct way to use this Monad.

Without going into details about the project, I have another function that manipulates the lists and returns a list if there is a solution.
The question is, should this function always return a `[String]` since there is nothing that can create a computation error, or should I use `Maybe [String]` to signify that the computation has found no solutions ?

```
solve :: [String] -> [String]
-- Found -> [String], Not found -> []
solve :: [String] -> Maybe [String]
-- Found -> Just [String], Not found -> Nothing
```

Comment: Both cases are perfectly well suited for the `Maybe` type. The empty list could also mean that the solution _is_ the empty list.

Comment: It does not sound like a bad idea to me, though for the first case in Haskell they also use the type [`Either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) for values that may contain errors. It is a monad, as well. For the second case, I'd personally prefer the empty list (not found -> `[]`).

Comment: I would `solve :: X -> [X]` and return *all* solutions. Then an empty list serves well as the "found no solutions" marker; if your consumer only needs one solution, it can only look at one (and only pay the price of finding one).

Comment: And since `[]` is *also* a monad, you can chain several solution steps together, if the solution to one problem is the input for the next (as when evaluating a game board, for instance). `solve initialBoard >>= solve >>= solve >>= solve ...`, which build up longer and longer lists of boards reachable from the original board.

Comment: The suggestion by @DanielWagner is a good one. In the special case where there can be only zero or one solutions, then `solve :: X -> Maybe X` would be better.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I think I object to the edit changing `[[Char]]` to `[String]`. At least if *I* wrote `[[Char]]` in my code, I would be communicating (or attempting to communicate) something different to the reader than if I wrote `[String]`. Since we can't see into Yuon's mind, it seems premature to change the communication in that way without checking in first.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm curious; I can understand `[[a]]`, but when would you ever use `[[Char]]`? Doesn't *hlint* suggest changing `[Char]` to `String`?

Comment: This is just a constraint given by the assignment I am working on. We are being given a maze from a file, and we have to find the shortest path. "Mazes are initially encoded as a list of lists of characters (– i.e.[[Char]]) in which every character denotes a cell." I just chose to keep the same type throughout the project, and conceptually it makes more sense that we are dealing with single characters that have specific meanings instead of considering a whole row as a String.

Comment: @Yuon Should I roll back my edits?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I don't mind either way, I don't think it changes the question that I asked. We could just change it to [a].

Comment: @DanielWagner in the context of the project we want to find the shortest path, which doesn't guarantee a single solution since multiple paths can have the same length. If I were to use a function  `solve X ->[X]`, i.e generating all the paths,is there a way to guarantee that `take 1 $ solve maze` would return the shortest path ?

Comment: @Yuon Of course. With your proposed type, you return at most one solution, so you must have an idea about how to choose that solution; whatever tricks you would use to choose that solution can be used to choose the order of results in the list if you return many solutions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons I like Haskell is that the type system is so expressive. When functions are well-designed, the type of a function takes the place of much (although not all!) documentation.

Often, `Maybe` is used to indicate that a function invocation can fail. A typical example is `lookup`:

```
Prelude> :t lookup
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

Here, you're trying to find a value in an association list, and it's fairly obvious that the operation could fail if the key isn't in the list. In this case, there's only one thing that can go wrong, so you don't need any other information than the presence or lack of a return value.

Sometimes, however, an operation can fail in more than one way, and you want to give callers a chance to distinguish between various different causes. In that case, `Either` is a better option, since you can let the *left* case carry information about the type of error.

Finally, when returning lists, you can sometimes use the empty list to indicate that no other result could be found.

Wrapping a list in a `Maybe`, then, is only useful if the empty list `[]` is fundamentally different than `Nothing`. If I see a function that returns `Maybe []`, I know that I, as a caller, will have to deal both with `Nothing`, but also with any list value, including the empty list.

Just by looking at the type signatures in the OP, it's not clear to me how `Nothing` is different from `[]`, but this could just be my lack of in-depth knowledge of the particular domain being modelled. It *does*, however, seem a bit odd.

Comment: When you say a function invocation can fail, are we talking about run time failure or conceptual failure, as in, unable to find the value due to the lack of a key ? 
Should I use Maybe strictly as a "catch exception" mechanism ?
Could you also provide a simple example of when you would prefer to return a Maybe [] instead of simply [] ?

Comment: @Yuon I can't think of an example where I would return `Maybe [a]`. Usually, `[]` carries the same meaning as `Nothing`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Say I have a database storing my customers and orders. I may have a function `ordersFor ::  SomeMonad m => m (Maybe [Order])`, where `Nothing` means "What customer? I've never heard of this person!", but `Just []` means "I found the customer, but no associated orders". This is nice, because e.g. I can say `fmap (sum . fmap orderProfit) <$> ordersFor someone :: SomeMonad m => m (Maybe Profit)`. The `SomeMonad` layer handles database errors. The `Maybe` tracks whether the the customer was found. It would be very weird to use just `[]` and get `0` when the answer is "Not found".

Comment: @Yuon Use `Maybe [a]` when you expect exactly 0 or 1 list; use `[[a]]` if you expect 0 or more lists.